# App indexing Android Activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-app-indexing

I am trying to configure app indexing and running into issues with "Fetch". Below is what I have configured:

1. Added and verified the website and app `/apk`
2. Associated website and the apk `/` app.
3. Added following configuration under the activity tag in **AndroidManifest.xml**

   ```
   <data
       android:host="mywebsite.com"
       android:pathPrefix="/mypage"
       android:scheme="http" />
   <data
     android:host="mywebsite.com"
       android:pathPrefix="/mypage"
       android:scheme="http" />
   ```

On the fetch page - `"android-app://package-name/"` [already present / displayed on the page].

I entered the following on the text field - `http://mywebsite.com/mypage`, uploaded the debug apk (as the current version on google play doesn't have deep links). On verify, i get URL unsupported error. This is baffling me as I am following the exact steps mentioned in support / tutorial links.

Also, i noticed that the path displayed is not correct, this is what I see is `/http:/mywebsite.com/mypage`.

Please help, its been days since I am trying to resolve this.. have gone thru all the links several times but no luck.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enter your URL in a different format. Required format for deep-linking is:

```
android-app://your.app.package.name/schema/host/path
```

In your case, you would use:

```
android-app://your.app.package.name/http/mywebsite.com/mypage
```

In "Fetch as Google" screen, you already have first part completed, so you only need to enter the following in the text field:

```
http/mywebsite.com/mypage
```

I also noticed that you are using the same data element twice in your intent-filter, so you can remove one.